# Delete property based on the property value xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for a logic to delete the property from an xml file based on the value of the propety.
In the following example:

```
<jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
       <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
          DELETE
       </jndi:value>
 </jndi:binding>
```

is having a value called "DELETE", whereever I see a word "DELETE" in an XML file, that particular property has to be deleted.

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
            name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
            <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
                <jndi:bindings
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                    xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">                   
                    <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                          <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                                @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                          </jndi:value>
                    </jndi:binding>
                    <jndi:binding
                        name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                        <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            DELETE
                        </jndi:value>
                    </jndi:binding>
                    <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcFileNet">
                          <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                                @myabcdefService.myabcFileNet@
                          </jndi:value>
                    </jndi:binding>
                </jndi:bindings> 
            </attribute>
        </mbean>
```

The Expected output is:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
            name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
            <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
                <jndi:bindings
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                    xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">                   
                    <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                          <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                                @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                          </jndi:value>
                    </jndi:binding>

                    <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcFileNet">
                          <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                                @myabcdefService.myabcFileNet@
                          </jndi:value>
                    </jndi:binding>
                </jndi:bindings> 
            </attribute>
        </mbean>
```

This is similar to the question that I asked earlier but the only difference is property format.
[Delete node from xml using xslt based on node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950377/delete-node-from-xml-using-xslt-based-on-node-value/17950861#17950861)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are hiding one of your requirements, it seems to me that the answer is just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:j="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="j:binding[normalize-space(j:value)='DELETE']"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And looking at the link you pointed to, I see that what I've done is a lot like what is done there.  What happened when you tried to do what was done before?

Comment: i get the following error when i use the above code, `XPST0081: XSLT Pattern syntax error at char 12 on line 11 in {j:binding[normalize-space}:
    Undeclared namespace prefix {j}`instead i tried the following code and it worked.`<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()='DELETE']"/>`

Comment: ... or you could just define the namespace prefix `j`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Ken idea, the following code worked `<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()='DELETE']"/>`.